# I Can't run odoo with command line (EDIT)

Tags: configuration-files, odoo-10

Hello I'm using Odoo 10e and Ubuntu 16.04,

I used to open Odoo with the command :

```
/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/odoo --config /etc/odoo/odoo.conf
```

or

```
python /usr/bin/odoo -c /etc/odoo/odoo.conf
```

EDIT :

In my case I stopped the service and try to execute the command above.
But here I have the following error :
[image]
But i can't connect as root, if i do 'sudo it's' written Running as user root is a security risk

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone helped me to resolve this : 
I had to use "chown" on the directory

`cd /opt/odoo` and `sudo chown -R adquat .local`

I think `sudo chown -R adquat /opt/odoo/.local` is correct but i don't tested it

So now i can run Odoo with the command `python /usr/bin/odoo -c /etc/odoo/odoo_custom.conf`

Comment: I have got some random deconnection bugs but it works quite well